# Send data directly to local computer from android app via WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi, data-transfer, data-sharing

I am building an android app, a part of which is to transfer an image DIRECTLY to a java program locally running on my computer using WiFi. I found out that i can do it by creating a homegroup in my local computer (windows 8.1) and put the image on that folder. But couldn't find any resources on how to connect my android app to the homegroup. Any suggestions or link will be much appreciated.

N.B: image must be sent directly (using one hop).

Comment: You're doing things in just about the hardest way possible.  The easiest way would be to have an HTTP, FTP, or similar server running on your computer.  Trying to do so via workgroups-  you need deep integration with MS specific protocols, including MS specific authentication if it isn't a public share. And MS has never been open about those protocols.  I'd rethink your approach completely.  In fact I'd probably rethink everything from base principles-  what is this app on your computer doing that an app on your phone couldn't?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll look forward to it :)

Comment: Have you thought about using the java program on the pc listening on a tcp port? I did a test a while ago but the opposite way around but the same principle. http://wlgfx.com/programming/tcp-android-client-and-server-code/